# do action method for JSlider like .doClick() for JButton

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton, jslider

I know I can trigger an action of a JButton indirectly by calling .doClick on the button.
Is there a similar method to call the action of a Slider indirectly (without actually moving it) ?
thnx

Comment: JSlider obj = new JSlider(); obj.setValue(number);

Comment: yeah but, i don't want to set a nez value, i want it to do the action with the current value it is having.. and i think obj.setValue(obj.getValue()) is messy coding ... or maybe it isn't ? :p

Comment: I don't think there is another way.

Comment: ok was not sure about this. thanx for the confirmation :)

Comment: Why not simply have the listener delegate to a method, and call this method?